# Any howtos on de-Xen'ing a box?

Tags: lvm, raid

I have a box that has Xen on it.  It currently has only one DomU.  Given that Xen isn't supported in the newer versions of Ubuntu...are there any good HOWTOs or other instructions for removing Xen?

My specific situation is:
 3 drives mirrored via RAID1 software raid.
 LVM on top.

I was thinking something like removing one of the drives, getting my DomU to boot of that and then re-RAID1 from that drive.  But I'm not really sure how to go about doing that with `mdadm`. :-/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know raid setups, but I think you are forgetting the problem that you need package changes to boot a xen system in an ordinary way.

There are xen-specific packages like libc-xen and xen-specific kernels.
You either want to chroot into it and revert those packages to normal. After that the partition could behave like a normal server setup.

But for your sanity, i would just backup your data and reinstall.

You may also want to investigate if it's possible to migrate Xen to KVM. That is: turning the partition into a qcow2 file.

Comment: I looked at KVM, but the Server CPU doesn't have VT support. I must have bought it *just* before they became common on all server hardware. :-(

Comment: re: backup and restore data...I'm hesitant to do that because this box has been around since 1995...(it was originally SLS then redhat then Debian then Ubuntu).  While it's configuration has gotten simpler over the years...I wouldn't call it simple. :-/

Comment: Well. Bootup with a recent Ubuntu disk or something. Get a fresh drive or partition. (like I said, i'm not familiar with raid setups). Copy/rsync all the files to the partition. Then chroot into it, replace libc and the kernel with the normal non-xen variants and reinstall grub and you should be fine. If you backup your whole partition and have a way to restore it, you can take some risks and play around.

Comment: So, I've already spent about 20 hours on this, and haven't had success. *sigh*  On the plus side, I think I'll succeed the next time. Oh boy.